# Sziklai pair style amplifier design

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, hobbyist

[image: Amplifier Schematic]

I am a beginner. I have built this schematic in LTspice. It's a five transistor amplifier with 2 voltage gain stages, 1 input stage, 1 output stage and 1 pair of Sziklai pair transistors. On testing it in LTspice with an 8 ohm load  it shows satisfactory results. It differs from the typical differential input stage - VAS stage - class B output stage design. Is this design usable in real life? If so, what changes can be made to improve this design? For example adding compensation capacitors and so on.

R1 and R2 control the gain as expected. Changing R4 from 1k - 100k does not have any effect on the circuit. R3 = 1k is the only value the gives a gain of 100 when R1 and R2 are set accordingly. I don't understand why that is so.

[image: Edited Image]

Edit: I did what was suggested in the comments and this was the result. I'm not sure what I am seeing on the output.  I suspect it is due to the oscillations caused by the poor design.

Comment: Have you considered that using models of real transistors might affect things?

Comment: I hadn't considered that.

Comment: Try right-clicking each transistor, and set them to actual parts.  The "NPN" and "PNP" LTspice models are very basic.

Comment: Also the 8 ohm load is going to affect the DC bias and there will be a DC voltage on the load, try adding a large value capacitor between the output and load, something like 470uF or more.

Comment: @rdtsc I did what was you suggested.

Comment: It's oscillating and you need to add compensation such as a 10 pF capacitor between Q4's collector and base. 10 pF might be too much or it may be too little of course.

Comment: @HarshitBujarBaruah Before delving into signals, small or large, I'd recommend using `.OP` to verify that your design is properly biased. After that, you can combine `V1` and `V2` into only one source with `SINE(0.7 50m 1k)`. Maybe also add a series resistance.